# Redirect all but a few requests

Tags: .htaccess

I have been forwarding my domain scotnery.com to jugglegood.com for a long time. Now, I would like to host a single page on scotnery.com (the index page) with css, img, and js. I would like to redirect all other requests to jugglegood.com because some sites might have links to "scotnery.com/tv" which i would like to be sent to "jugglegood.com/tv"

here's my current htaccess file at scotnery.com which is not working for me and seems complicated

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|other-page)\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule .* http://jugglegood.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the resulting htaccess file contents. A friend helped me out...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js|index\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://jugglegood.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```